# Buffered Reader, Line count, Split, Parse in Java

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, split, bufferedreader

Actually, I am assigned a task where I have a xyz.txt/CSV file which will basically have numeric values and I am supposed to pass it through BUFFERED READER then split those values and finally parse them.

So I have a Java code can body help me with it.

```
package javaapplication12;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;

public class JavaApplication12 {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String count= "F:\\Gephi\\number.txt";            
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {           
            fr = new FileReader(count);
            br = new BufferedReader                       

            // AT THIS POINT THERE SHOULD BE SOME THING THAT COUNTS NUMBER OF LINES USING COUNT++ OR SOMETHING LIKE THIS//    
            String sCurrentLine;    
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }                            
        }             
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)
                       br.close();

                    if (fr != null)
                       fr.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }            
     }
}
                // COMING TO THIS POINT THE ABOVE VALUES OF .TXT FILE SHOULD BE SPLIT USING SPLIT PARAMETER//
               // AFTER SPLITTING THE SPLIT VALUE SHOULD BE KEPT IN AN ARRAY AND THEN EVENTUALLY PARSED//
```

Or IF Anybody can rewrite the code in another way of the above-stated problem, it shall also be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `StringTokenizer` or `String.split()` to split each line of your file to different tokens and count each of them. See [StringTokenizer.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and  [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: Yes, I know about Str.split() but I don't know how or where to put it in my code. I having difficulties in writing the code with split, count and parse.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to take a look around and see how to ask a proper question, to increase the chances to gave some good answers from the community: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I see that this was the problem statement given to you and you didn't even try solving it by yourself. I recommend you to at least try to understand the problem and code it. That is the best way to learn how to program, rather than asking for a solution.

Comment: Put mentioned code in the while loop, where is reading file line by line. For each line tokenize it. You could also define a `Map<String, Interger>` to count each value.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for welcoming pls don't jump onto conclusions such as I didn't try and I'm looking for solutions, I have been working on this since past 7 days and couldn't get proper help, so I came here seeking help. Even now I am trying and I think I could split it, looking forward to parsing portion help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution with Java 8:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.stream.Collectors;

 public class BR {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "br.txt";
    //for the csv format
    String regex = ", ";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        List<String[]> lines = br.lines()
                .map(line -> line.split(regex))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        parse(lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void parse(List<String[]> lines) {
    //Do your stuff here
}

 }
```

The initialization of the BufferedReader is in the try block (this approach is called try with resources), since BufferedReader implements AutoCloseable (an interface), so in case an exception is thrown the reader will close.

The br.lines() method returns all lines from the file.
In the map function you are passing a line that is rad in a lambda. The line is split using the split variable (for CSV format it is ', ') and is returned and collected.

The result is a List of arrays of String which can be changed in the body of the map function.

For more clarification I suggest you check some Java 8 tutorials and you will fully understand what is going on.

This solution might not be appropriate for your knowledge level (I guess), but hope it inspires you to check some fancier and modern approaches.

Have a nice day.

Comment: TQ ur help is appreciated.